# iphone , read 2 rows with one section in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, indexing

i want to create one `section` with 2 `rows` in `uitableview`
for convert this code i have a lot of problems

here is code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
NSString *mytext = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\r",[[Itemes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"MUSIC"]];
```

i want convert to this style :

```
NSString *text = [Itemes objectAtIndex:([indexPath section]*2 + [indexPath row])];
```

Comment: please explain what you mean by read 2 rows with one section

Comment: the uitableview is dynamic and i want the tableview read all the 2 rows in one section i know the convert style is work but i can not do that for this format i give a lot of error

Comment: can you converting the first line code to secend line @suhit

Comment: how many sections do you have?

Comment: -(NSInteger)numberOfsectionsInTableView:(UITableview *)tableview
{
return items.count/2;
}
@suhit

Comment: what is item array count?

Comment: is count the mytext string saved in array

i want only write first line code to second line code but is difficult for me i am not good in nsstring @suhit

Answer (score 0):

You try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
  arrValue = [dic objectForKey:@"Music"];
                if(arrValue==nil) {
                    arrValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    [dic setObject:arrValue forKey:key];
                    [arrKey addObject:key];
                }
  [arrValue addObject:ref];
 }
```

Use in table

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [[dic objectForKey:[arrKey objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[dic objectForKey:[arrKey objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: i want to have 2 @"MUSIC"  in one section @payal

Comment: my seconds line codes is correct but i can not convert the first line code to second @payal

Comment: check my updated answer. ref is your object of music,what you pass.

Comment: i want somthins like this 

 NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:([indexPath section]*2 + [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"MUSIC"])];
    i get an error expected unqualified-id @payal

Comment: print value [indexPath section]*2 + [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

When you get your Items array, Do this

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMuatbleArray New];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary New];

for(NSInteger i = 0; i<[Itemes count]/2 ; i+=2) {
 {
   for(NSInteger j = 0; j<2 ; j++) {
    {
        NSString *text = [Items objectAtIndex:(i+j)] objectForKey:@"MUSIC"];
        [dict setObject:text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    }
    [array addObject:dict];
}
```

In Tableview Datasource Methods

Edit: in dictionary setObject:forKey takes only string as key.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfsectionsInTableView:(UITableview *)tableview { 
         return items.count/2; 
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
           return 2; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ObjectForKey:[indexPath.row integerValue]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i have one error in  [dict setObject:text forKey:i];

Cannot initialize a parameter of type id <NSCopying> with an LValue.. @suhit